# Show boolean values in table using semantic-ui-react

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I am new to React and semantic-ui-react.  I am creating a table to display a few values, including a boolean, from a mongo database.  The column header is defined like this:

```
<Table.HeaderCell
  width={2}
  textAlign="center"
  sorted={column === "activeFlag" ? direction : null}
  onClick={this.handleSort("activeFlag")}
  >
 Active
</Table.HeaderCell>
```

And the table rows are rendered like this:

```
{_.map(data, ({ repoName, repoDesc, activeFlag }, index) => (
     <Table.Row className="devRow" key={index} active onClick={e => this.updateRepo(index)}>
        <Table.Cell>{repoName}</Table.Cell>
        <Table.Cell>{repoDesc}</Table.Cell>
        <Table.Cell textAlign="center">{activeFlag}</Table.Cell>
      </Table.Row>
     )
  )}
```

activeFlag was originally defined as Boolean with default value false, but the value did not appear in the table.  When activeFlag was redefined to be a String, then the value appeared in the table.  Can boolean values be shown in a table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that nothing is shown in this line,

```
<Table.Cell textAlign="center">{activeFlag}</Table.Cell>
```

is due to that `activeFlag` is a real boolean value and not a string or number..

So to display any boolean value in template, you could use the following,

```
<Table.Cell textAlign="center">{String(isActive)}</Table.Cell>
```

If you want to display a literal "true" or "false" you should convert it to a string and then display.

> **Working Sandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-drag-table-rows-k45i

Comment: Tq, using  String(isActive) i'm able to print boolean value.